# Project relative paths in cypress code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, code-climate

I'm using Cypress for client e2e testing and **@cypress/code-coverage** for reports. I have a **monorepo**, client and server folders. Each one generates its own coverage report (lcov.info). I am using CodeClimate for keeping track o total coverage. It provides a tool to merge multiple reports into one, and then upload it
The problem is that both reports have relative paths (regarding the tested files) to is service, so /client/coverage/lcov.info does not build path as `'client/component/index.ts'` but `/component/index.ts` so report merging fails

I can fix this on the server side passing some options to jest-conf, but I didnt fine nothing related to cypress. I can generate the report folder/files in the root level passing an option to nyc (which is used under to hood by @cypress/code-coverage), but the paths are still relatives to the client folder.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Help much appreciated

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?  I'm running into a similar issue running cypress tests in vercel and needing to find a way to pass in the relative path.